# Is there any support for BiPlots when using PCA in spark.ml?

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, pca, apache-spark-ml, dimensionality-reduction

I have used kmeans and PCA to attempt to visualise high dimensional k-means clusters in two dimensions but have lost the meaning of the clusters in 2D.

Is there anyway to project the features onto to 2D plot to return some interpretability?

Answer (score 0):

Any [non-linear dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction) method might work better (also called "manifold learning", e.g. see [sklearn's suite](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html)). The [t-sne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding) method is generally quite popular for this.

However, these do not take your cluster labels into account. If you wanted to do that (although generally you *do not*), you could add a penalty to the manifold learning technique that forces same-cluster points to be close together, for example.